# Reading huge amount of data 50Million from database and writing it to Fixed width and BSON Multithreading slower than serial writing

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have been trying to read 50 Million records from DB2 as a compressed stream and would then like to create 2 jar files one of them in fixed width format and the other in the BSON format.

I have been able to make the code work but since the time taken to pull the code and write it to these files takes close to 120 minutes I redesigned the code to use a producer consumer model. I how ever see performance being degraded using this model. Multi-threading for some reason is not working as expected.

Producer producer = new Producer(queue1, queue2, url, user, pass, driver, strQuery);

```
          Consumer1 consumer1 = new Consumer1(queue1, outputDatFile, fileDat.getName());
          Consumer2 consumer2 = new Consumer2(queue2, outputDatBSONFile, fileBSONDat.getName());
          ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
          Future producerStatus = threadPool.submit(producer);
          threadPool.execute(consumer1);
          threadPool.execute(consumer2);
          try {
                 System.out.println("This will wait for the producer to wait " + producerStatus.get());

          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
          threadPool.shutdown();
          long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
          System.out.println("End Time: " + end);
          long elapsedTimeMillis = end - start;
          float elapsedTimeSec = (float) elapsedTimeMillis / 1000.0F;
          System.out.println("Total Time: " + elapsedTimeSec + " seconds..");
          if (!(errorStatus)) {
                 System.out.println("Successful exit...");
                 System.exit(0);
          } else {
                 System.out.println("Exiting - Fatal Errors Encountered!");
                 System.exit(1);
          }
   }

   private static JarOutputStream getJar(String outputDatFile, String fileName)
                 throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
          JarOutputStream jarOutPutStream = new JarOutputStream(
                       new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputDatFile + ".jar"))));

          jarOutPutStream.setMethod(JarOutputStream.DEFLATED);
          JarEntry ze = new JarEntry(fileName);
          jarOutPutStream.putNextEntry(ze);
          return jarOutPutStream;
   }

   public class Consumer1 implements Runnable {

          private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
          private String outputDatFile;
          private String datFileName;
          public Consumer1(BlockingQueue<String> queue, String outputDatFile, String datFileName) {
                 this.queue = queue;
                 this.outputDatFile = outputDatFile;
                 this.datFileName = datFileName;
          }
          @Override
          public void run() {
                 JarOutputStream jarOutPutStreamText = null;
                 try {
                       jarOutPutStreamText = getJar(outputDatFile, datFileName);
                       int recordsWritten = 0;
                       while (true) {
                              recordsWritten++;
                              try {
                                     String objectRetrieved = queue.take();
                                    jarOutPutStreamText.write(objectRetrieved.getBytes());
                                     jarOutPutStreamText.flush();

                                     if (recordsWritten % 100000 == 0) {
                                            System.out.println("Written Records Count Queue 1 " + recordsWritten);
                                     }

                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                              }
                       }
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                       e1.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e1) {
                       e1.printStackTrace();
                 } finally {
                       if (jarOutPutStreamText != null) {
                              try {
                                     jarOutPutStreamText.close();
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                       }

                 }

          }

   }

   public class Consumer2 implements Runnable {
          private BlockingQueue<DBObject> queue2;
          private String outputDatBSONFile;
          private String bsonFileName;
          public Consumer2(BlockingQueue<DBObject> queue2, String outputDatBSONFile, String bsonFileName) {

                 this.queue2 = queue2;
                 this.outputDatBSONFile = outputDatBSONFile;
                 this.bsonFileName = bsonFileName;
          }
          @Override
          public void run() {
                 JarOutputStream jarOutPutStreamBSON = null;
                 try {
                       jarOutPutStreamBSON = getJar(outputDatBSONFile, bsonFileName);
                       BSONFileWriter bsonWriter = new BSONFileWriter(jarOutPutStreamBSON);

                       int recordsWritten = 0;
                       while (true) {
                              recordsWritten++;
                              try {
                                    DBObject objectRetrieved = queue2.take();
                                     bsonWriter.write(objectRetrieved);
                                     bsonWriter.flush();
                                     if (recordsWritten % 100000 == 0) {
                                            System.out.println("Written Records Count Queue 2 " + recordsWritten);

                                     }
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                              }
                       }
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                       e1.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e1) {
                       e1.printStackTrace();
                 } finally {
                       if (jarOutPutStreamBSON != null) {
                              try {
                                     jarOutPutStreamBSON.close();
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                       }
                 }
          }
   }

   public class Producer implements Runnable {
          private BlockingQueue<String> queue1;
          private BlockingQueue<DBObject> queue2;
         private String url;
         private String user;
          private String pass;
          private String driver;
          private String strQuery;
          public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> queue1, BlockingQueue<DBObject> queue2, String url, String user,
                       String pass, String driver, String strQuery) {

                 this.queue1 = queue1;
                 this.queue2 = queue2;
                 this.url = url;
                 this.pass = pass;
                 this.driver = driver;
                this.strQuery = strQuery;
          }
          @Override
          public void run() {
                 Connection con = null;
                 Statement st = null;
                 ResultSet rs = null;
                 try {
                       Class.forName(driver);
                       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                       con.setAutoCommit(false);
                       Map<String, Object> mapper = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                       try {
                              st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                              st.setFetchSize(20000);
                              System.out.println(

                                            "Attempting to execute statement: " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + strQuery);

                              strQuery = strQuery.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");

                              rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);

                              ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                              try {
                                     int col = md.getColumnCount();
                                     int resultSetCounter = 0;
                                     while (rs.next()) {
                                            String strQueryOutput = "";
                                            resultSetCounter++;
                                            for (int x = 1; x <= col; ++x) {

                                                    String outPut = "";
                                                   if (md.getColumnTypeName(x).equals("DECIMAL")) {
                                                          StringAlignUtils util = new StringAlignUtils(md.getColumnDisplaySize(x),
                                                                       Alignment.RIGHT);
                                                          outPut = util.format(rs.getString(x));
                                                          strQueryOutput = strQueryOutput + outPut;
                                                          mapper.put(md.getColumnName(x), outPut);
                                                   } else if (md.getColumnTypeName(x).equals("NUMERIC")) {

                                                          StringAlignUtils util = new StringAlignUtils(md.getColumnDisplaySize(x),
                                                                       Alignment.RIGHT);
                                                          outPut = util.format(rs.getString(x));
                                                          strQueryOutput = strQueryOutput + outPut;
                                                          mapper.put(md.getColumnName(x), outPut);
                                                   } else if (md.getColumnTypeName(x).equals("CHAR() FOR BIT DATA")) {

                                                          char charData = rs.getString(x).charAt(0);
                                                          outPut = charData + "";
                                                          StringAlignUtils util = new StringAlignUtils(md.getColumnDisplaySize(x),
                                                                       Alignment.RIGHT);
                                                          outPut = util.format(outPut);
                                                          strQueryOutput = strQueryOutput + outPut;
                                                          mapper.put(md.getColumnName(x), outPut);
                                                   } else {

                                                         StringAlignUtils util = new StringAlignUtils(md.getColumnDisplaySize(x),
                                                                       Alignment.RIGHT);
                                                          outPut = util.format(rs.getString(x));
                                                          strQueryOutput = strQueryOutput + outPut;
                                                          mapper.put(md.getColumnName(x), outPut);
                                                   }
                                            }
                                            if (resultSetCounter % 100000 == 0) {

                                                   System.out.println(" The counter is " + resultSetCounter);

                                            }

                                            strQueryOutput = strQueryOutput + '\n';

                                            queue1.put(strQueryOutput);
                                            queue2.put(new BasicDBObject(mapper));
                                     }
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                     System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                     System.err.println("Exiting!");
                                     System.exit(1);
                              }
                              System.out.println("Query results successfully returned...");
                       } catch (SQLException s) {
                              System.err.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
                              System.err.println("Error: " + s.getMessage());
                       } finally {
                              System.out.println("Trying to Close ResultSet and Statement...");
                              if (rs != null) {
                                     System.out.println("Closing ResultSet..");
                                     rs.close();
                              }
                              if (st != null) {
                                     System.out.println("Closing Statement..");
                                     st.close();
                              }
                       }
                 } catch (Exception exception) {
                       exception.printStackTrace();
                 } finally {
                       try {
                              System.out.println("Trying to Close database connection..");
                              if (con != null) {
                                     System.out.println("Closing database connection..");
                                     con.close();
                              }
                       } catch (SQLException exception) {
                             exception.printStackTrace();
                       }
                 }
          }
   }
```

Comment: Please remove all the blank lines so we can read your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the reason why the file was getting generated in incorrect format.

There are 2 problems

1) Complete data was not being written.
2) Stream was not being closed.

The problem is fixed but even after having 1 Producer and 2 consumers the time taken to process is upwards of 90minutes for 50 Million records can some one point me the areas that might make this program faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are sufficient elements that slow things down.

One small error

```
String objectRetrieved = queue.take();
jarOutPutStreamText.write(objectRetrieved.getBytes());
```

Maybe for the last `else` left aligned?

Should specify the encoding

```
jarOutPutStreamText.write(objectRetrieved.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

The easiest to spot:

```
String strQueryOutput = "";
```

should be

```
StringBuilder strQueryOutput = new StringBuilder(1000 /* output size */);
```

The DB2 SQL may benefit by a last line `WITH ur` (uncommited read).

The `StringAlignUtils` should be created once, outside the loop.
In fact leaving it to the database to format might be the fastest solution.

If you need to pass a map for every record, you can prepare a map, and hold an array of `Map.Entry` entries by column index (minus 1). To immediately alter the value by column index.

A smaller fetch size (?) and more java heap might help to.

My experience in this field concern mainly **GzippedOutputStream** (which I would have expected here too), where the fastest compression is not the highest compression.

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes as suggested above that helped, I have how ever noticed that writing to a file with out zipping is faster than writing to a zipped stream. Writing to BufferedWriter takes approximately 14 minutes to process 1 million records and 22.8 minutes to write to a zipped stream.